# How can I make linear graphs from multiple groups?

Tags: r, graph, correlation

I am quite new to R and trying to get the hang of things but I seem to have some trouble with some simple analyses. I'm not 100% sure how to explain what it is I am trying to do but I will do my best. This is a screenshot of my dataset:
[image]

It shows the NAICS (which is an industry grouping code) the year and the Net Sales of different companies. NAICS is now shown as only 315 but there are 49 different codes in the 3285 observations.
What I would like to do is make a correlation graph per industry with year on the x-axis and Net Sales on the y-axis. Is there a simple way of doing this without having to type out the code for all 49 industries?

I am sorry for the formatting but this is my first time posting on stackoverflow so still have to get used to it.

Comment: So, each dot will be sales for one industry in one year? Do you want to plot different industries in the same graph with different colours, or in different graphs on their own?

Comment: So as the data set is there are multiple years of data for multiple companies per industry. I would like to have singular graphs per industry (as 49 plots on a single graph would be too chaotic) where all the values per year are a dot and then a line of the aggregate (?) per year from 2016-2020. I would like to see whether CoVID-19 had an impact on the average Net Sales per industry.

Comment: First aggregate the companies using `dplyr`, something like `industries <- companies %>% group_by(naics, year) %>% summarize(sales = sum(sales))`. Then use ggplot2. Do something like `ggplot(industries, aes(year, sales) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(vars(naics))`.